# How to write update query in mongodb for deeply nested array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have a Model `Customer` and its schema

```
var customerSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required:true, trim: true, index: true, default: null, sparse: true},
    cardInfo: { type: [cardInfoSchema]}
})

var cardInfoSchema = new Schema({
    customerId : { type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true,trim : true,  sparse: true},
    cards: { type:[cardsSchema], default:[]}
}, {_id: false});

var cardsSchema = new Schema({
    cardType   : { type: String, required: true, default: null, trim : true },
    isActive   : { type: String, required: true,  trim: true }, //0: not active, 1: active
    cardId     : { type: String, required: true,  trim: true },
    createdAt  : { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true }
})
```

I want to add multiple cards of customer so I am using this

```
var dataToSet = {
                    'cardInfo.customerId': '25934285649875',
                    $push: {
                        'cardInfo.cards': {
                            cardId: 'somecardid,
                            cardType: 'type',
                            createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
                            isActive: true
                        }
                    }
                };
```

But I am getting this error.

> cannot use the part (cardInfo of cardInfo.customerId) to traverse the element ({cardInfo: []})

Please help me in writing the query to add card of customer using mongodb or mongoose.

Comment: Please show us your full mongodb/mongoose request example.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **[`positional $`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator in your update which acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document, and when you use it make sure the `cards` array field must appear as part of the query document. In your case you'd want to add a `card` document into the `'cards'` array, but only if the `cardId` doesn't exist:

```
var query = {        
    "cardInfo.cards.cardId": { "$nin": ["somecardid"] }
};
var update = {        
    "$push": {
        "cardInfo": { "customerId": "25934285649875" },
        "cardInfo.$.cards": {
            cardId: "somecardid",
            cardType: "type",
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
            isActive: true
        }
    }
};

Customer.update(query, update, function (err, result) { ... });
```

Comment: This is my query and it is not working

`db.customers.update({"_id" : ObjectId("12345689")},
 {
   "$push": {
        "cardInfo": { "customerId": "25934285649875" },
        "cardInfo.$.cards": {
            cardId: "somecardid",
            cardType: "type",
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
            isActive: true
        }
    }
   
 },
 {}
 )`
Getting This Error:
`WriteResult({
  "errmsg" : "The field 'cardInfo' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId('12345689')}"
})
`

Comment: Make sure the cards array field must appear as part of the query document i.e. `db.customers.update({"_id" : ObjectId("12345689"), "cardInfo.cards.cardId": { "$nin": ["somecardid"] }}, { "$push": { "cardInfo": { "customerId": "25934285649875" }, "cardInfo.$.cards": { cardId: "somecardid", cardType: "type", createdAt: new Date().toISOString(), isActive: true } } }, {} )`