# How to pull data from deeply nested array in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi I have deeply nested array in my mongoose schema. I want to pull record from that deeply nested array. Can anyone please help in writing the moongoose query. I tried this

```
var condition = {
                    _id: user,
                    $and: [
                        {
                            'cardInfo.cards': {
                                $elemMatch: {
                                    _id: cardId,
                                    isActive: '0'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            'cardInfo.cards': {
                                $elemMatch: {
                                    _id: { $exists: true }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]

                };
 var dataToUpdate = {
      $pull: {'cardInfo.cards': { _id: cardId }}
 };
 var options = {
      lean: true
 }
```

for schema please look at [MyAnotherQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759652/how-to-write-update-query-in-mongodb-for-deeply-nested-array) and please try to answer that question as well. Above query is not working but in mongodb it is working fine if I use `ObjectId` for cardId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have been able to resolve the issue. What I did is just added an another parameter in options variable like:

```
var options = { strict: false, lean: true}
```

`strict: false` is the parameter which made my query to work and my mongoose query is same i.e

```
Customer.update(condition, dataToUpdate , options, anycallback)
```

and yes it is working for me.